# Как использовать и обращаться с многомерными массивами?

Tags: c#, .net

Я новенький в программировании и уже освоил основное понятие массивов, однако я не совсем понимаю операций с ними и как с ними в принципе необходимо обращаться. Прошу объяснить мне, что да как. Я серьёзно не могу понять их структуры, особенно, когда у них больше, чем одно измерение.
Конкретно о проблеме: я не могу понять, как проходят простейшие операции с двух- и многомерными массивами, с массивами массивов.

Comment: Мне уже кажется, что я зря это сделал...

Comment: Вас минусят потому что вы написали текста много, но в нем нет конкретной проблемы. Вот если вас кто спросит `как нужно жить?` вы сможете понять и решить его проблему?

Comment: Я не могу понять принцип работы операций с массивами ранга выше, чем 1 и массивами массивов, сейчас отредактирую и напишу подробнее.

Comment: `Я не могу понять принцип работы операций с массивами ранга выше, чем 1` для меня это просто список слов. Я не понимаю, что это значит. Что конкретно не получается?

Comment: У вас какая то задача или что? Если у вас задачи нет, вы просто теорией интересуетесь - читайте книжки и вот если там конкретный вопрос будет не ясен, спрашивайте.

Comment: Вы же не ждёте, что кто то вам сейчас будет расписывать всю теорию по массивам ещё и так, чтобы было лучше, чем в учебниках?

Comment: Например, я хочу получить число из двухмерного массива, как я должен это сделать? Указать ряд и столбец, в котором находится данное число? Также я не могу понять, как выводить все числа из подобных массивов. Минут 5 писать не смогу, прошу прощения.

Comment: В двумерном массиве вам надо указать да, два индекса, по индексу на каждое измерение. То есть чтобы извлечь значение из двумерного массива вам да, надо знать условно строку и столбец.

Comment: Чтобы вывести все значения массива, надо пройтись по всем его индексам, по всем значениям. Представьте себе поле в клеточку и у каждой клеточки есть номер строки и номер столбца. Вот вам надо по всем строкам и столбцам пройтись

Comment: Понял, большое вам спасибо.

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.4.php